# Why did this discord.js mass role removal code stop working?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a bot that when given the command would remove a specified role from all members who had it.  This worked relatively well until recently and I'm not sure why it has stopped now.  It will remove the role from my profile but no others.  I know there was a recent update but from what I can tell nothing should have affected this code.  Here is the basic block of code that appears to not be working.

```
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
 member.roles.remove(roleID)
})
```

I do not receive any errors.  It just doesn't remove the role from anyone else but my own profile.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` over at the discord developer portal?

Comment: It is enabled.  Again it was working until this past week or so.  Nothing had changed on my end.

Comment: I'm no really sure what happened but it appears to be working again now.